# Score calculation for two different teams

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet, formulas

How would i go about counting the scores between **C1** and **C8**  and entering the values into **A2** and **B2**?

```
a1 = blue

b1 = red


a2 = team blue score

b2 = team red score
```

between **c1** to **c8** = winning team & score **(NOTE: c1 = $a$1&" 1.25" )**

```
 c1 = blue 1.25
 c2 = blue 2
 c3 = red .5
 c4 = draw
 c5 = blue 1.5
 c6 = blue 1.75
 c7 = red 2
 c8 = draw
```

So what I should get is:

```
A2 should =  6.5
B2 should =  2.5
```

Comment: If you can have helper columns then from C1 you can separate numeric and text portions in helper columns by the following formulas. Numeric portion ~=VALUE(RIGHT(C1,(LEN(C1)-LEN($A$1))))~ and the text portion by ~=LEFT(C1,(MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},C1&"0123456789"))-2))~ I am learning about formulas and still a long way to go.

Comment: I gave a Google Sheets answer, seeing its tag; but then there is also "excel-formula"? Please decide which of these two **different** products you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the total score of the blue team with

```
=sum(arrayformula(if(left(C1:C, 4)="blue", value(regexreplace(C1:C, "[^0-9.]", "")), 0)))
```

For the red team, use `left(C1:C, 3)="red"` in the formula.

The conversion from text to number happens in two steps: `regexreplace` removes all characters except . and 0-9;  then `value` converts text to number.

---

It would be better to keep the winning team and their score in separate cells (team in column C, their score in column D), which would simplify the handling of this data: you'd only need `=sumif(C1:C, "blue", D1:D)`.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i was trying to do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Taking help of helper columns and without Array formula.These formula can adapt if you change team to Green or any other colour.
Formula in D1:(And Fill down)

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(C1,(LEN(C1)-LEN($A$1))))
```

Formula in E1:((And Fill down)

```
=LEFT(C1,(MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},C1&"0123456789"))-2))
```

(And Fill down)
Formula in A2:

```
=SUMIF(E1:E9,"blue",D1:D9)
```

Formula in B2:

```
=SUMIF(E1:E9,"red",D1:D9)
```

[image: Snapshot of result]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input skkakkar, I did try what you suggested, however Soup's answer was more practical in my case

Comment: @Bert Starington I also wanted something like Soup's answer and have also mentioned to you in my comments that I have a long way to go. Happy to have your feedback. Thanks.